# Can i call a JS script in knockout databinding?

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I need to invoke a JS function inside a foreach loop in knockout data-bind.

I need to do something like:

```
<div data-bind="foreach:items()">
.....
<script>
  jQuery(function () { jQuery('#myid').rateit({ value:$data.value }); })
</script>
....
</div>
```

Obviously it doesn't work, i've not found a way to apply data binding inside a script tag ... is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

If you want to execute something for every item in a collection (or on *any* observable) you can use a [`computed observable`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html).

This would work in your scenario:

```
ko.computed(function () {
    var items = this.items();

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        jQuery(function () { jQuery('#myid').rateit({ value: item[i].value }); })
    }
}, viewModel);
```